# Unable to present a BitmapSource properly

Tags: wpf, bitmap

I have a program which generates a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and then uses it to create a `BitmapSource`. I then assign the `CurrentImage` property of a WPF `Image` to the `BitmapSource` I create.

And here is the problem: no matter what I set the DPI values of the `BitmapSource` to, I end up with a grainy picture on my 4K display.

The piece of XAML I'm using is:

`<Image Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>`

and the code is as follows:

```
private static void SetBitmap(FreeformEditor fe, Bitmap bmp)
    {
      if (fe.lastBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
        DeleteObject(fe.lastBitmap);

      try
      {

        var data = bmp.LockBits(
          new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
          ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        var dpi = baseDPI * (1 + fe.RenderForRetina.ToInt());
        fe.CurrentImage = BitmapSource.Create(
          data.Width, data.Height, dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null,
          data.Scan0, data.Stride * data.Height, data.Stride);
        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        fe.lastBitmap = bmp.GetHbitmap();
        fe.imageSizeRun.Content = string.Format("{0}x{1} @{2}dpi", fe.CurrentImage.Width,
                                                            fe.CurrentImage.Height,
                                                            fe.CurrentImage.DpiX);
      }
      catch
      {
        // this happens due to framework bugs
      }
    }
```

Comment: What's the original resolution of the bitmap you're generating?

Comment: @EdPlunkett the original resolution is either 96 if I'm on an ordinary monitor or 192 if I'm on Retina

Comment: So for the moment assume we're on an ordinary monitor. 96 dpi, and how many inches high/wide?

Comment: @EdPlunkett say, 21.5" but why should it matter? All I'm trying to do is ensure that the pixels in the bitmap correspond 1:1 to the pixels on the monitor

Comment: Some people do stuff like creating a bitmap that's actually 100x100 pixels and then they think they can change the DPI on it and it'll act like a vector graphic. But that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Just a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the `Image.Source` Binding is pointless.

Comment: @Clemens thanks, doesn't help my issue though

Comment: It isn't clear what your issue is. What exactly is a "grainy" picture, and how is it different from what you expect? How does it look if you set `Stretch="None"` on the Image control?

Comment: @Clemens no change. by 'grainy' I mean the image gets rendered at what appears to be 96dpi. what I want to do is have it rendered at *system DPI*, whatever that is on a given system